# How to update decorator on file save?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, decorator

I have created a plugin with decorator which takes current file as input and show appropriate decorator.

This is working fine and decorator is shown properly when the eclipse loads for the first time.

However, when file changes, decorator is not updated.

How can I update decorator every time file is modified? i.e. How can I update decorator on file save event?

This is the sample code

```java
public class Decorator implements ILightweightLabelDecorator {

    private final ImageDescriptor OVERLAY1 = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "icons/1.png");
    private final ImageDescriptor OVERLAY2 = AbstractUIPlugin.imageDescriptorFromPlugin(Activator.PLUGIN_ID, "icons/2.png");

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IBaseLabelProvider#addListener(org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener)
     */
    @Override
    public void addListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IBaseLabelProvider#dispose()
     */
    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IBaseLabelProvider#isLabelProperty(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)
     */
    @Override
    public boolean isLabelProperty(Object element, String property) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IBaseLabelProvider#removeListener(org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILabelProviderListener)
 */
    @Override
    public void removeListener(ILabelProviderListener listener) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     *
     * @see org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ILightweightLabelDecorator#decorate(java.lang.Object, org.eclipse.jface.viewers.IDecoration)
     */
    @Override
    public void decorate(Object element, IDecoration decoration) {
        if (some_condition)
            decoration.addOverlay(OVERLAY1);
        else
            decoration.addOverlay(OVERLAY2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ask the `IDecoratorManager` to update decorations with a specific id using:

```java
IDecoratorManager decoratorManager = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getDecoratorManager();

decoratorManager.update("decorator id");
```

To do this on file save you will have to use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen to workspace resource changes and react when you see your file being changed.

Set up a listener with:

```java
ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```

In the `IResourceChangeListener` you can do something like:

```java
public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
    IResourceDelta delta = event.getDelta();

    IResourceDelta fileDelta = delta.findMember(IPath of file you are interested in);

    if (fileDelta != null) {
       // TODO handle the delta
    }
}
```

Comment: Will it be proper to set up listener by adding  `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener)`  to `addListener(ILabelProviderListener)` method of `ILightWeightDecorator`? What can be other procedure to set up listener?

Comment: You could add it in the decorator constructor (and remove it in the dispose method).